# ¿Como configurar single sign on (SSO) en Wildfly 10?

Tags: java, jsp, wildfly, single-sign-on

Actualmente tengo un login y varios wars y deseo que al loguearse pueda pasar mi objeto Usuario por session a los demás wars.

¿Como configuro mi servidor Wildfly 10 para que todos mis wars desarrollados en JSP puedan comunicarse sin necesidad de crearle un login a cada war?